# Simple polymer script not working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm new at `polymer` and my first script is not working...

My code:

**index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js></script>

    <link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
</head>
<body>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

**hello-world.html** (Update):

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hello-world" noscript>
<template>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({is: "hello-world"});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

The libraries:

`polymer.html`: http://pastebin.com/jd1rxAuH

`wecomponents.js`: http://pastebin.com/yBaJpFBi

Uploaded here: https://www.sese7.de/polymer/

I don't know what i've done wrong, thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be read at [Polymer Migration Guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration).

> The `<polymer-element>` tag is no longer used to define an element. In this release, these are replaced by a `<dom-module>` element (to define local DOM and styles) and the `Polymer` call (to register the element).

A working example can be seen at http://webcomponents.org/hello-world-polymer/bower_components/hello-world-polymer/ where the hello-world.html is defined similar to:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="hello-world">
    <template>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        // the is is important here since it specifies the element name
        Polymer({is: "hello-world"});
    </script>
</dom-module>
```